# Wi-Fi network created but not allowing connection to the Internet

Tags: macos, wifi

I am able to create the Wi-Fi signal through my MacBook Pro, though it doesn't connect to internet when I use it in other devices.

I am using OS X Yosemite and I tried to use the Wi-Fi created from my Mac in my Lenovo tablet and Samsung smartphone.

I called Apple service and they say they cannot help for I am not using Apple tablet and Apple smartphone.

Comment: you are talking about Internet (WiFi) sharing. So what is your set up? how do you get internet to the Mac (WiFi or cable). What do you mean by WiFi created ?

Comment: @Buscar웃  I am using the internet through cable, and try to share it to other devices of mine using wi-fi sharing. As I wrote in question, network gets created and detected, but access to internet is not happening for some reason. Apple guys are also not helping.

Comment: ok, that set up should work regardless of device type.  And you do not have a restriction on the receiving site (from your provider) to open more then one connection. Do you get the self assigned IP on the other devices?

Comment: What is the address assigned to your Mac on your Ethernet port?

Comment: @JaimeSantaCruz I.P Address 172.17.14.32, Subnet Mask : 255.255.252.0, Router : 172.17.12.14, I hope I answered your question

Comment: Yes, thanks; I thought it may have been a conflict between the public address or network segment an the network created by your Mac but it does not seem to be the case.

Comment: @JaimeSantaCruz I have a feeling that I have to do some network setting in the device I am using.

Comment: What device is it? What is your external IP? How many and which devices between your Mac and the Internet?

Comment: @JaimeSantaCruz I use Samsung smartphone and Lenovo Yaga Tablet. Please shed some more light on "external IP" for I dont know what if is?

Comment: http://whatismyip.com will give you your external IP; I was asking between your Mac and the Internet, is there a router, a modem?

Comment: @JaimeSantaCruz Proxy:
No Proxy Detected
City:
Dijon,    
State/Region:
Bourgogne,    
Country:
FR - fr flag,    
ISP:
Universite De Paris Sud,    
Your IP:
194.199.165.11.........if this is what you asked for...

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to try is to enable `Internet Sharing` from `System Preferences -> Sharing`.

[image: Internet Sharing panel]

Now choose the right source and destination, connect your device to WiFi shared network and try to navigate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, As I have already done that. I successfully created the network and my devices detects them as well. But the problem is access to internet. network doesn't access internet. and I dont know why?